# Regex matches on exclusion/inclusion of a word with various possessiveness then a key word

Tags: python, regex

1. I want to look for various types of matches on the word "car" but not if its preceded by "Jane, Jane's, Janes, and Jane(s).

the following 2 regex partially work for exclusion and inclusion, but I can't get the other variants to work

- (?<!\bJane) car
- Jane car

for example

- the car is red  - Match
- here is Jane car is red  -> None
- here is Janes car is red  -> None
- here is Jane's car is red  -> None

2. I also want to find the cases Jane is in the phrase

   - the car is red  - None
   - here is Jane car is red  - Match
   - here is Janes car is red  - Match
   - here is Jane's car is red  - Match
3. and where car is not preceding by Jane(s)

- here Jane(s) car is red  - None

4. and of course the opposite

- here is Jane(s) car is red  - Match

**Edit**

If I have a document with "red car\n and Janes car"  this should be a Match as there is a reference to "car" without the word Jane/Janes/Jane's/etc. in front of it.

In fact, for additional clarity.  I will be doing a re.Findall for all the occurrences of "car" without the word Jane in front of them.

Comment: 1. If there is a match on 'car' not preceded by 'Jane' or a variation thereof, what is to be returned, `true/false`, the entire string, a match of any part of the string or something else? 2. What is to be returned for the string `'Jane's red car'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match it where the different forms of `Jane` should not occur, you can exclude the match with a negative lookahead, and then still match `car`

```
^(?!.*\bJane(?:'?s|\(s\))? car\b).*\bcar\b.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*\bJane(?:'?s|\(s\))?` Match `Jane` `Janes` `Jane's` `Jane(s)`
  - `car\b` Match a space and the word car
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `.*\bcar\b.*` Match the whole line with the word `car` between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7moyzc/1)

If the different forms of Jane followed by car should be there, you can match it:

```
^.*\bJane(?:'?s|\(s\))? car\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6QYxLd/1)

To matching all occurrences of `car` without the ones that have `Jane` in front of it, you can match what you don't want to keep and capture what you do want to keep.

Then in Python you can use `re.findall` which will return the capture group values and remove the empty entries from the result.

```
\bJane(?:'?s|\(s\))? car\b|\b(car)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UdBW8Q/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TXSqcA)

Comment: why do I need "car" in and out of the look ahead?  was using a look behind wrong?  and thank you.  I would never have gotten this.

Comment: @QuentinJS In the lookahead, you can make sure that the string does not match `Jane car` but if the string still has to contain the word car you would still have to match it. Python re does not support a quantifier in a lookbehind like `(?<!\bJanes?)` You would have to account for that with an alternation listing all the posibilities like `(?<!\bJanes)(?<!\bJanes)(?<!\bJane's)(?<!\bJane\(s\)) car` and you could have a single match for car where all the assertions are true https://regex101.com/r/9sf5Pe/1

Comment: @QuentinJS But if you want to rule out the whole line if there is a match, using a lookahead is more versatile as you don't have the problem with the quantifiers in the lookbehind. There is another option for the lookbehind to work with the quantifier and that is using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

Comment: Will this work in a document where I could have both "Janes car" and on another line red car.  Also if there is word wrap and its Janes\ncar I should be able to just replace the space with a \S ?

Comment: @QuentinJS It really depends on what you want the pattern to match. If the pattern has to match car, but excludes matching `Janes car` only, it can match car in `red car` If you have really different scenario's I think writing separate patterns is more readable and maintainable than a single long pattern with all sorts of scenario's (And only if those scenario's are also possible without being mutually exclusive)

Comment: sorry to confuse., red is not a match condition, only 'car' , I was trying to clarify and I confused instead.  A doc could have the word car and the phrase 'Janes car'.  it should still find the word car in the document.

Comment: @QuentinJS If you just want to match car, you can use `\bcar\b` If you optionally want to match Jane as well you can make the whole group optional , see for example https://regex101.com/r/qD4EGJ/1

Comment: I updated updated question.

Comment: @QuentinJS If you want to match all occurrences of car without Jane in front of it `\bJane(?:'?s|\(s\))? car\b|\b(car)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/UdBW8Q/1 Then if you use re.findall it will return the capture group values (which are hightlighted in green in the regex101 link) Like this for example https://ideone.com/TXSqcA